# Implementing ActivityIndicator while axios fetch data from an api

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement an `ActivtyIndicator` while axios fetch data from an api.

I've set up my **context** which looks like this.

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'PULL_JOB_FEED_DATA':
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const jobFeed = (dispatch) => {
    return async () => {
        const response = await serverAccess.get('/jobFeedData');
        dispatch({ type: 'PULL_JOB_FEED_DATA', payload: response.data });
    }
}

export const { Context, Provider } = dataContext(
    reducer,
    { jobFeed },[]
);
```

and using the context inside **home.js** like below where I tried implementing the `ActivityIndicator`

```
const JobSearch = ({ navigation }) => {
const [loading, setLoader] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
        jobFeed();
        setLoader(false);
    }, []);

    return (<View>
           {loading ? <ActivityIndicator /> : <Text>Content to be displayed otherwise</Text>}
         </View> );

};
```

Indicator however doesn't show up as expected. I presume I shouldn't set the setLoader state to false inside useEffect hook, not sure how else I can set to false. If there is a better way to implement this, appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your useEffect function. You are calling an action (jobFeed) that calls an async function inside. You should wait for your async call result and show the loading state accordingly.

```
useEffect(() => {
        jobFeed();
        // remove this. setLoader(false);
}, []);
```

To make this work properly, you can either move the async call into your component or move the loading state to your reducer.

```
const jobFeed = (dispatch) => {
    return async () => {
        dispatch({ type: 'START_LOADING_DATA' });

        //you also need to add here a try and catch block.
        const response = await serverAccess.get('/jobFeedData');

        dispatch({ type: 'PULL_JOB_FEED_DATA', payload: response.data });
    }
}
```

and change your reducer to something like the following

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'PULL_JOB_FEED_DATA':
            return {...state, payload: action.payload, loading: false};
        case 'START_LOADING_DATA':
            return {...state, loading: true};
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

I didn't understand how you created your context but the idea is getting the payload and loading state from your reducer and show it in the component. 
Hope that this helps.